# Can I get my laptop fn-keys to work in Ubuntu?

Tags: samsung, function-keys

I have a Samsung Series 5 laptop, model NP535U3C-A01SE. I recently decided to try Ubuntu and installed 12.04 LTS. One thing that bothers me is that my function keys don't work properly.

I read on a blog that I could install Windows drivers using ndiswrapper, then I noticed that the fn-keys need Windows software to work, not drivers.

I then stumbled across this question, [samsung new series 9, not all function keys working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172613/samsung-new-series-9-not-all-function-keys-working). Explains how to get brightness keys to work. Seems like he couldn't get all fn-keys to work though.

Any ideas?

(I'm new to Linux btw, not familiar with commands)

Answer (score 0):

I belive it is important to know what keys are you having trouble with...
I had a problem adjusting brightness on my acer aspire one and it was solved modifying grub... What problems do you have?

Also, this appears similar to your problem and it is answered already...
[samsung new series 9, not all function keys working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172613/samsung-new-series-9-not-all-function-keys-working)