# esc and function keys not working properly on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, function-keys

I'm using a Samsung Book with a brazillian portuguese keyboard.
Esc key isn't working at all, When I press f7/volume down and f8/volume up the volume goes all the way down or up and then those keys don't work anymore until I log out and back again. Other function key aren't working properly too.
[image: keyboard layout]

This is the keyboard layout, I have it as Portuguese(Brazil).

Comment: Have you tried any solutions yet? [I found this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172613/samsung-new-series-9-not-all-function-keys-working). You can most likely skip the part about updating the BIOS and the question is old so you can ignore the stuff about the kernel version as well.

Comment: I also found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/28077/167115). Although, it does seem a bit old, the concept seems the same.

Comment: I need a step-by-step solution I don't want to be messing with that stuff if I don't know for sure it's going to work, also those question are outdated.

Comment: If this is a rather new machine, you may have more success with a more recent Ubuntu version. Try with a live USB/DVD of forthcoming Ubuntu 22.04, and if that does not have the problem, install that version instead. It is officially still beta, but as it will be released within less than a week, it essentially is already in final form.